# How can i get the Current Date Time value of Ontario,Canada in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to find the current date time value of Ontario, Canada. I have used following code but it does not work:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("20130930","yyyymmdd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-CA"));
```

where `20130930` is today's date, i.e. 2013-09-30.  I want the output in yyyymmdd format.  I have also tried:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("20130930","yyyymmdd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("FR-CA"));
```

but it displays the result as `30-01-2013 00:09:00`.  Can anyone please tell what is the mistake I have made and correct if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your format string is incorrect

try with `yyyyMMdd`

if you need to convert date time back to string

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("20130930","yyyyMMdd",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-CA"));
string result =  date.ToString("yyyyMMdd",  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In DateTime Formats `MM` is for months and `mm` is for minutes

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

You can convert your current time to UTC and then use that to find the date time of canada using `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method, but you need to know the `TimeZoneId` ( [this will help you](http://www.xiirus.net/articles/article-_net-convert-datetime-from-one-timezone-to-another-7e44y.aspx))

```
var result =   TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Atlantic Standard Time"));
```

Comment: Yes i just missed out thank you it worked perfectly. Can u suggest me what if i even want current time along with date?